# How can I limit the number of chars/words in a long text field to 3000?

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I would like to limit the amount of text that my users can input in a text field. I want it to be a text area so I made a field called "Solution" then I made it a type "Long Text" and a widget type of "Text Area." I would like to limit the number of characters that the user can post to 3000 characters. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Maxlength](http://drupal.org/project/maxlength) module does that.

Comment: Thanks, a lot of times I just can't find the right search term to find modules

Comment: Make sure you mark the above as an answer if it was what you were looking for.